# Percentage Calculation on MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

Im new to MDX Query and I'm trying to add a percentage on attended percentage in each row.  The following code :

```
SELECT {[Measures].[Client Interventions Count]* [Dim Intervention Attendance].[Attended].Children} ON COLUMNS,
[Dim Date].[Calendar].[Month Name] ON ROWS
FROM [Client Intervention]
```

procude a result of :

[image]

How can I perform a calculation on each row? For example, first row November 2007 , total client intervention count = 68 , so the percentage count should be 57/68 %

Any idea?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a calculated member - you can find several examples [here](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Calculated%20Members.html). The idea for the query is as following:

```
WITH MEMBER [Dim Intervention Attendance].[Attended].[%] AS
    ( [Dim Intervention Attendance].[Attended].[Attented],
       [Measures].[Client Interventions Count] )
  / ( [Dim Intervention Attendance].[Attended].[Not Attented], 
      [Measures].[Client Interventions Count] )

SELECT  
  [Measures].[Client Interventions Count] 
   * { [Dim Intervention Attendance].[Attended].[%], 
       [Dim Intervention Attendance].[Attended].Children } ON COLUMNS,

  [Dim Date].[Calendar].[Month Name] ON ROWS

FROM [Client Intervention
```

]